# How to navigate to a named route while poping it self?

Tags: flutter

I have a **Start** screen with a `pushNamed` button.

How do I discard **Start** screen after I reached to **rules** Screen?

```dart
onPressed: () {
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
          '/rules',
         );
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean?
you want to go, to screen2 from screen1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [Navigation documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

You can use `pushReplacementNamed` instead of `pushNamed`.

By using this your first screen will be removed from the screen stack. In your case, if you use the below code your `start` screen will be replaced with `rules` screen.

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/rules);
}
```